# Why does the Google Analytics events are not working when the site is loaded via Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-analytics

I have 2 websites A and B

A has google analytics in it. A is loaded in B via Iframe. When I access A directly I can see GA events being pushed but when I access A via the iframe in B I cannot see the GA events.

What can be done to make Google analytics in Iframe working?

Html for A

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i.GoogleAnalyticsObject = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
        }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga'));
        window.ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'auto');
        window.ga('send', 'pageview')
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    hi
</body>

</html>
```

Html for B

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8080" width="100%" height="600" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "when I access A via the iframe in B"? Did you remember to tell your dev tools to look at A's frame instead of B? What are you not seeing? Console activity? Or actual events logging over on Google's analytics website?

Comment: If I access website A directly I can see google analytics APIs being called in the network tab. But if I check website B where A is loaded as iframe I  can see B requesting analytics.js file but the google analytics API is not being called in the network tab

Comment: That would make sense: if you want to see the iframe's network activity, attach the dev tools to that iframe, because it's literally a different page. Google for how to do that with the specific browser you're using, and if that browser doesn't allow that, grab a different one that does.

Comment: Did you change the filter to review the requests for the iframe?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In the latest chrome we can see the network activity from the parent's network tab. And I am not able to see any data from GA dashboard which points to the fact that GA inside an iframe is not wokring

Comment: @epascarello I did not know about such a filter. Do you think that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. We fixed the problem with this workaround.

In the iframe:

```js
if (inIframe) { // Check if in iframe
    // Send to parent page
    window.parent.postMessage({ action: 'iframe-message', event: event, status: status }, '*')
} else {
    // Send to Google directly
    ga(`send`, 'event', event, status)
}
```

Parent page:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
    if (message.data.action !== undefined && message.data.action === 'iframe-message') {
        // Send to Google
        ga(`send`, 'event', message.data.event, message.data.status)

    }
}, false)
```

Code not complete, change with your own variables.